# Installing addtional Vim helptags on Windows (x64)

Tags: vim, windows64

I have been finally trying to get up to speed with Vim, in this case on Win 64 So I have Vim installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\
and I have added the DB plug in which seems to be working but I want to configure the help file the inst says to run :helptags $VIM/vimfiles/doc from in Vim but I get  C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\doc not found (note the reference to the Program files and not the x86 version)... I've tried changing the directory in Vim to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\doc and variations.... but have not found the "secret combo to unlock this beast!?

These file path issues between platforms are a bear!

Comment: Well Duh,, I realized that I had installed both the 32 bit and the 64 bit versions,, So now having "properly configured the 64 bit version,,, (which by the way I must run as admin to get anywhere) But still now I get a different error when running :helptags $VIM/vimfiles/doc to get the help configured for dbext.vim now I get E154: Duplicate tag "/MyProjectDir/" in file C:\program Files\vim\vimfiles\doc/dbext.txt   

Any clues??

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem; my .vimrc had called helptags (I thought it would be a great idea to put it there), anyway, once I removed that helptags call, the error went away and I STILL could get help on dbext from vim. I'm assuming now that you do not need to call helptags except for possibly once, not on every vim start.